# Table Stacking Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Good day everyone, first time asking for help.

I am attempting to build a supply chain builder, essentially I want the user to press a button to activate a macro that will Prompt them to identify how many points are in their supply chain.  The number they input would then create a table 3 columns wide by X number of supply points entered.

From there, each time they press the button to generate a new table, that table would need to appear below the one created prior.

Some users may have 3 chains, others may have 10.  Regardless, in my template each user would press the macro button for each Supply Chain they have and each time they do this it creates the table underneath the prior created table.

Hope this makes sense!

I have not had any luck with this, however I did attempt a macro that would just modify an existing table.  My issue with that is when you resize a table it wont work if it ends up overflowing into one below.

So ideally, I would want it to be dynamic like what I wrote above.

Currently using this code to get the first table to paste.

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when first column has value on last row and first row has a value in the last column

Dim i As Variant
i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("test")
Set StartCell = Range("c" & i)

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
  
  Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the table's header? Are you looking to include a blank row between adjacent tables for separation?

Comment: Due to me being new, didn't even see this comment.  My bad.  Yes, that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's essential to validate user input before proceeding.
- You can create a table without selecting the range.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListObject.HeaderRowRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm734084)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub DynamicRange()
    Const COL_CNT = 3 ' cols count in the table (ListObject)
    Const COL_KEY = 1 ' used to determine the last row
    Dim i As Variant
    i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets("test")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
    With sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
    End With
    Dim tabRng As Range
    Set tabRng = sht.Range("A" & LastRow).Resize(i + 1, COL_CNT)
    Dim objTable As ListObject
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
    objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = Array("Col1", "Col2", "Col3") ' for testing
End Sub
```

---

Update:

> Question: I need the tables to start on N4 when the user starts to use this macro

```vb
Sub DynamicRange()
    Const COL_CNT = 3 ' cols count of the table (ListObject)
    Const COL_KEY = "N" ' used to determine the last row
    Const FIRST_ROW = 4
    Dim i As Variant
    i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set sht = Worksheets("test")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
    With sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
        If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = 4
    End With
    Dim tabRng As Range
    Set tabRng = sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, COL_CNT)
    Dim objTable As ListObject
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
    objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = Array("Col1", "Col2", "Col3") ' for testing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `to make the new tables past in with the columns already labeled`.

Comment: Should be my last question, how do I get the first table to not paste until Row 4?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "first table"? I'm unable to revise the code until I receive answers to my questions.

Comment: Right now it works as should almost.  It puts the first table created in A1, downward with correct rows.  Then when user enters the maco again, it creates another able directly under the 1st one created, and so on and so on.    Problem is, I need the tables to start on N4 when the user starts to use this macro.  Not A1

Comment: Thank you so much for the help yesterday, I was able to take your code and build it out to create tables dynamically other worksheets as well.  I am however running into an issue, I was hoping to get the column headers to be dynamic and tied to a cells value in the worksheet.  I dont want to type each column header in the code as they will change with each report.  I need the column headers to match a cell value.  How do I this?

Comment: Got it, please understand I am new to this site.  Literally just signed up yesterday.